# Disable all screen touches when button is pressed

Tags: android

I am using a constrained layout, and I'm trying to disable screen touches when a button is pressed. I've seen methods of making a transparant layout on top and setting it clickable, but I dont know how to implement it and have been unsuccessful. My activity-main.xml is below:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getimagebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:text="Upload Image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="152dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a `View` as a cover/mask:

   ```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/mask_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.5"                         //half transparent
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clickable="true"    //absorb the focus, no need "focusable" which is for EditText
        android:visibility="gone" />
   ```
2. Control the visibility:

   ```
    disableButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            maskView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       //set to "GONE" when the task is finished
        }
    });
   ```

Tutorial: https://youtu.be/qpZdDzJt618
Demo: https://youtu.be/nwTkKx5-_jQ